# Adding Leading Zeros to Records + Cast

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an incremental field for each record in my table.

I want to add leading zeros to the number to make them all the same number of characters but also CAST() letters to the front of the number as an identifier.

Adding the leading zeros;

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, No_), 6)
```

Adding my identifier;

```
SELECT 'FC' + CAST(No_ as varchar(50))
```

What is the correct syntax for combining these two statements to the one field? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT 'FC' +RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, No_ ), 6)
```

**Result**: For No_  = 1

```
FC000001
```

For No_  = 222

```
FC000222
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
SELECT 'FC' + RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, No_), 6)
```

Comment: To make the each value the same length, i think the problem is the hard coded zeros.

Comment: @stb: No. What he does here is implementing a way of doing `LPAD` as this doesn't exist in T-SQL.